# Getting error while using get_cost_and_usage in lambda with boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to get the cost of the previous day using cost explorer while using `boto` and `lambda`. But I get and error

> " "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when
>   calling the GetCostAndUsage operation: " and the error type is
>   "ClientError".

I have specified the region to `us-east-1`. Also my policy is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ce:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My Code is below

```
ce = boto3.client('ce')

cost = ce.get_cost_and_usage(TimePeriod={'Start': '2019-7-15', 'End': '2019-7-17'}, Granularity = 'DAILY')

print(cost)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two problems:

1. Invalid timestamp formatting, that will cause an error like this:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetCostAndUsage operation: Start time  is invalid. Valid format is: yyyy-MM-dd.
```

2. Missing the mandatory `Metrics` keyword to the `get_cost_and_usage()` call.

Changing your `get_cost_and_usage()` call to something like this should work:

```
cost = ce.get_cost_and_usage(
    TimePeriod={'Start': '2019-07-15', 'End': '2019-07-17'},
    Granularity = 'DAILY',
    Metrics=['UnblendedCost'])
```